# Wrap vertically like a column in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am using Div base Submenu on my site. I like to wrap vertically with a fixed-height sub menu.

I create a menu and sub menu using div. I don't want to use Ul,li. My structure is like...

```
<div class='submenu">
    <div class="menu"><span>item1<span></div>
    <div class="menu"><span>item2<span></div>
    <div class="menu"><span>item3<span></div>
    <div class="menu"><span>item4<span></div>
    <div class="menu"><span>item5<span></div>
    <div class="menu"><span>item6<span></div>
    <div class="menu"><span>item7<span></div>
    <div class="menu"><span>item8<span></div>
    <div class="menu"><span>item9<span></div>
    <div class="menu"><span>item10<span></div>
</div>
```

Now when I run this code and hover on menu then submenu must display like:

item1    item6
  item2    item7
  item3    item8
  item4    item9
  item5    item10

When the height of submenu height is fixed like **200px**, the number of submenu dynamic will be 10 or 15 or anything. I need it using CSS.

Comment: what's with the closing tag </menu>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Used to** `Css3` Property **[column-count](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/)**

as like this

```
.submenu {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap:   20px;  
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -moz-column-gap:      20px;
  column-count:         2;
  column-gap:           20px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/6Np3p/)**

**[Demo-2](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/6Np3p/2/)**

Comment: yes that's right but i don't need column fixed. submenu increase dynamically . like 10 or 15 number of submenu there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CSS3 column-count Property` and you may add `display: table-cell;` also

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BgAB/)

```
    .submenu {
        max-height: 200px;
        column-count:2;
        -moz-column-count:2;  /* Firefox */
        -webkit-column-count:2;  /* Safari and Chrome */
        display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: disply: table-cell is not used. it will not divide into column

Comment: @ketan I know, I just added it to look what you want. Which is not 100% width. That's why I just added `you may` :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use CSS like this

```css
.submenu {

max-height: 200px;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 10px;

}
```

display: table-cell can also be used, but the width cannot be changed if only one column is present **(what I have experienced)**